# Jersey: different JSON filter for one DTO

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jax-rs, n-tier-architecture

I am using Jersey (JaxRS and Jackson).

I have a Student DTO.

```
class StudentDTO {
  private Integer id;
  private String name, className, grade;
  private String createdAt, modifiedAt;

  // getter, setter for all private members above
```

I want that DTO to be reused in create, read, and update.

But, for create, only name, className, and grade are allowed. For update, only className and grade are allowed.

My current solution is using three different DTO class, one for create, one for update, and one for read.

How to do that with only one DTO class?

Comment: You can try overloading constructor with required parameters you want..

Comment: Overloading constructor can't be used to filter request parameter. Jackson will map to class members even if they are private, not to getter/setter/constructor.

Comment: I personally think that 3 DTOs are better in terms of semantics. It gives proper documentation of the API without having to remember which fields should be present or not in every case. My two cents ;) Also if you can make them immutable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create custom serializer for every case. 
Create custom serializer by extending `StdSerializer<T>` and override the `serialize(T value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)` method and registrate it in ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(StudentDTO.class, new CustomSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

One more question. If you create an object, fields except name, className and grade are empty? Yow may try use annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` on class level.

Comment: Please improve the answer by including a relevant code snippit. Links tend to go out of date.

Comment: @M.leRutte Ok, no problem